# CBPgridgallery - How can I close slideshow by clicking outside content area?

Tags: jquery

I'm u using Google Grid Gallery for one of my project. Below is the link of that plugin reference site: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/google-grid-gallery/

I am not able to close popup slideshow by clicking out side of the content area. Can anyone help me for this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please show the relevant code parts you already have and explain in detail, what is not working.

Comment: If you check the above given reference url, The popup slideshow can be closed only by clicking close button. How can I close that by clicking empty overlay area? Like generally all popup close when we click out side white area, anywhere on overlay background?